# how to schedule a task with start time and end time using java Timer and TimerTask

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

Hi im developing some schedular which should start at a particular time and it should stop after some time.. starting after a delay i can do using timer and timerTask classes.. But stopping i dont have much idea. How to stop the timer after a elapsed time.

Comment: What does your code does once its trigger at particular time? Is it a non stop continuous process ?

Comment: No its not a non stop process.It should schedule the job only once time based on start time and stop time.

Comment: If its a non-stop process (for example send email at scheduled time ) then it would stop automatically once it completes that job. Do you mean you want to stop the scheduler itself ?

Comment: @jay : Im doing Tracing application my scheduler has to schedule the tracer thread at a particular time and stop at end time.. So only I want to stop the scheduler after the elapsed time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your task in a thread, you can keep a reference to the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object of the task and set a timeout. Something like that :

```
Future<?> future = executor.submit(new customTask()));
try {
    future .get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    // The timeout exception is thrown when the get times out. Handle your stop logic here
}
```

You might want to handle the InterruptedException, ExecutionException and TimeoutException separately.

You can also call the .cancel() method on the Future object when your stop timer expires, but I recall reading somewhere that it is not recommanded